# When I want to move my model It doesnt go smooth

Tags: interface

When I try to move it around with <kbd>G</kbd> it doesn't go smooth, it makes like big jumps and not smoothly... I'm in pose mode trying to make an animation.

Comment: Have you got the button "snap during transform" enabled (magnet icon)?

Comment: Ohh my god thanks! I'm a beginner I didnt see that one comming :')